# How to parse numbers with trailing sign?

Tags: java

How to parse numbers with trailing sign?

Example input:

```
Cnt    Market Variance  % Var.
----- ------- --------------------------
Borr     545    1,253,626,425.65  100.0+
Loan     841    5,102,373,724.22- 100.0-
```

Comment: If you knew the answer why have you asked the question here?

Comment: Because I wasn't able to find correct answer on Stackoverflow. This is knowledge-sharing https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I know is to provide two patterns - one for positive and one for negative numbers:

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = ((DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US));
    decimalFormat.applyPattern("#,##0.00;#,##0.00-");

    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("6.4+"));    // Double 6.4
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("724.22-")); // Double -724.22
```

Same can be obtained as BigDecimals

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = ((DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US));
    decimalFormat.applyPattern("#,##0.00;#,##0.00-");
    decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);

    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("6.4+"));    // BigDecimal 6.4
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("724.22-")); // BigDecimal -724.22
```

**WARNING**

Patterns are dependent on Locale. Skipping Locale can have unpredictable effect.

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00;#,##0.00-");
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("6.4+"));    // Long 6 WRONG!
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("724.22-")); // Long 724 WRONG!

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00;#,##0.00-",
            DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("6.4+"));    // 6.4
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse("724.22-")); // -724.22
```

**HINT**

You can parse number specifying start position without applying substring operation

```
    String line = "Borr     545    1,253,626,425.65  100.0+";
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse(line, new ParsePosition(16))); // 1253626425.65
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.parse(line, new ParsePosition(34))); // 100.0
```

Don't ask me why you need to wrap int with ParsePosition.

Comment: I [do not reproduce](https://ideone.com/rCLvow) your problem with the constructor, which JDK version was it?

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: So, Oracle's 1.8.0_171. I'm inclined to think you might have made a mistake while testing, because [this test](https://ideone.com/dG8pTJ) uses Oracle's 1.8.0_151 JVM and passes just fine.

Comment: Well, I found the reason for this discrepancy. It's because of Locale. Try to get instance for Locale.GERMAN and result will be different. I'll correct the answer, thank you.